# Applied Math Major Roadmap

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, education, book-recommendation

**A little background for my question:** I have been studying Math with a problem/solving strategy until very recent (mostly taking a bunch of interesting problems from contests like IMO and traying to solve them, and reading Engels' problem solving books), and so I feel comfortable with the basics methods for proving, and also with the basics of Number Theory, Geometry, and Discrete Mathematics. So far I have studied a little of Calculus (just finished Single Variable),and Probability Theory. Recently, I began to study Discrete Mathematics with a main focus on Combinatorics and Graph Theory, and I plan to start both Linear Algebra and Differential Equations as soon as I finish Multivariable Calculus.

---

I love Mathematics, specially what I have seen from Applied Math (although my background is very reduced yet), and I've been trying to build like a roadmap to self-study the subjects that I need (using the MIT Math major requirements). I will start college in about a year, but since I have the time I want to prepare and to learn as much as possible as I really enjoy Math, however I've been struggling with some of the technicalities of this idea of self-studying the major:

1. I'm not sure about which subjects I can start to study in parallel as for example both Linear Algebra and Probability Theory require Multivariable Calculus. I don't know if it suffices to study them at the same time of Multivariable Calculus, or if I should first study Calculus and then start the other subjects. And the same with other classes, I don't know what subjects I can start and until where to reach at a first encounter, and also where to go once finished. For example I don't know at which point I should start Real Analysis. Hence a roadmap for the Math major with some tips of what classes to take first and which of them I could take at the same time would be very helpful.
2. Any recommendation about the textbooks and materials (articles, books, courses, lecture notes, $\ldots$) to use for each subject is also very appreciated (I know that this particular point has been debated before in this forum but any new opinion is very welcome). I've been using MIT Opencourseware website so far and here is a list of the textbooks that I've been using for self-studying as well:

   - Calculus: [A Friendly Introduction to Analysis (Kosmala)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130457965)
   - Probability Theory: [Introduction to Probability (Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/188652923X)
   - Discrete Mathematics: [A Walk Through Combinatorics (Miklos Bona)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9813237457)
   - Abstract Algebra: [Abstract Algebra (Foote & Dommit)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471433349)
   - Linear Algebra (soon to begin): [Linear Algebra (Friedberg, Insel, and Spence)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130084514)
   - Algorithms and Data Structures: [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) and [Algorithm Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N2XUEZI)

Thank you for taking the time to read this!!! Any comment/critic/advice is welcome =)

Comment: You can always dive into a subject or book and then backtrack to fill in gaps as necessary. For probability, you might also want to read Blitzstein and Hwang. For vector calculus and linear algebra, you might like Hubbard and Hubbard (Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms). Div Grad Curl and All That is a good quick intro to vector calculus. Strang’s book Intro to Applied Math is a good general applied math book. Numerical Linear Algebra by Trefethen is a good book for applied math people. Algorithms Illuminated by Roughgarden is very good for data structures and algorithms.

Comment: About when to start real analysis, you could read Calculus by Spivak immediately and you’d already be learning real analysis.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your response! I will check all the book recommendations you just gave me.

Comment: Linear algebra doesn’t require really any calculus. Multivariable calculus might introduce you to a few concepts, but the meat of MV calculus is not a requirement.

Comment: Multivariable calculus does provide very good motivation for linear algebra though. The fundamental strategy of calculus is to take a nonlinear function $f$ (difficult) and approximate it locally by a linear function (easy). To make sense of this idea when $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, we must invent linear transformations. In order to understand linear transformations, we must invent linear algebra.

Comment: Thank you for the comments =) Does that mean that I could start to study Linear Algebra with only a basic knowledge of Multivariable Calculus???

Comment: Yes, you can dive directly into linear algebra if you’d like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you've learned single-variable calculus from Kosmala's analysis book and you'd like to know where to go once you've finished the rest of his book.

I'm not familiar enough with Kosmala's book to know whether it has enough practice with basic calculus problems. If you think it doesn't, you could use Maron's *Problems in Calculus of One Variable* alongside it.

After that, I'd say that the schedules of the undergraduate math program at Cambridge are likely to be a more transparent guide than the MIT undergraduate program as to what to read in what order, particularly as you say you're interested in applied math. Here are the most recent schedules: https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/files/schedules.pdf

And lecture notes: https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/studentreps/tripos-specific-resources

I believe you'll find that the physics books suggested there and in the lecture notes of some of the faculty (see David Tong's webpage in particular) are better suited to applied mathematicians (as opposed to physicists) in comparison with undergraduate physics courses taught in the United States.

I would sugeest that your next major steps should be to learn algebra (I really like Artin's book - it combines abstract and linear algebra nicely), and analysis at a higher level than in Kosmala's book (for example, Apostol's analysis text is great, and the second volume of Zorich should also be possible).

Before then, I'd try to learn enough about vectors and complex numbers from a geometric and algebraic standpoint to be comfortable when they come up in algebra or analysis, though you might find that Chapter 1 of Apostol's text is enough for you on these topics.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the info, and yes, that was exactly the problem about where to go after finishing the book. I have visited the links you gave me and they have been extremely helpful for that matter. I feel much more clear about what to study and in what order, and I agree that Tong's lecture notes are great for someone that is not a Physics major. After Probability Theory I plan to move on to Statistics, but I am unsure about what is next of Discrete Math (Combinatorics)?

Comment: I'm glad this was useful. I don't have any specific recommendations for discrete math. For probability and statistics, once you've studied multivariable calculus, I like David Williams' *Weighing the Odds*, though you may want to supplement it with one of the books mentioned in Part IA. After Kosmala, if you don't already know this material well, I think one of the books from IA Vectors and Matrices would be useful. But right after that you can move on to analysis and algebra, which are really the core of an undergraduate education. If you learn those, a lot of other things will become easier.